# Algorithm to find an approximation for a common factor of a set

Tags: elementary-number-theory, algorithms, computational-mathematics

Given a set of positive real numbers $X=\{x_1,...,x_n \}$ and let $\varepsilon>0$, how could one find the smallest $z>0$ such that $$\mid(z\cdot x_i)-f(z\cdot x_i) \mid<\varepsilon $$ for $i \leq n $, where $f(x)$ is the closest natural to $x$, and if two naturals are at the same distance of $x$, $f$ maps it to the even integer.

Thanks in advance

Also, by natural I mean a positive (non-zero integer), i.e. $f(0.002)=f(-32)=1$.

Comment: Note there's no *smallest* $z \gt 0$ which would work since as $z \to 0$, you have $z \cdot x_i \to 0$ for all $i \le n$, so $\left|(z\cdot x_i)-f(z\cdot x_i)\right| \to 0$ and, thus, would be $\lt \varepsilon$. Did you perhaps mean the largest $z \gt 0$ instead? Also, do you want your result to be true for at least one $i \le n$, or for all $i \le n$?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I edited my question to be more clear about what I need

Comment: Again, sorry about that. I thought  that I had changed the word integer.

Comment: If $x_i < 0$ for some $i$, $|(z \cdot x_i) - f(z \cdot x_i)|$ is a linear function with positive slope passing through $(0,1)$.  If $\varepsilon < 1$, then there is no $z>0$ that satisfies your condition.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer:

The condition may be unsatisfiable for most $\varepsilon < 1/2$.  As a random example, set
$$  X = \{8.44045, 7.62664, 3.16536, 8.96804, \\
5.16923, 1.63361, 8.11436, 4.27568, \\
3.11587, 1.10181\}  \text{.}  $$

Then simultaneously plotting $|z x_i - f(z x_i)|$ as $z$ ranges over $(0,1]$ yields

[image: Simltaneous plot]

While there may be a surprise coincidence allowing a solution in $z$ for a small value of $\varepsilon$, expect these to be rare.